# InfluxDB - query for current week

Tags: javascript, influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

How can I use the `boundaries.week()` [LINK](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/date/boundaries/week/) function from the `"@influxdata/influxdb-client"`?

The docs say I need to import `import "date/boundaries` but I don't know where.

I need to query the current week from Monday to now.

Here my current query:

```js
const weeklyPowerQuery = `
    from(bucket: "iobroker")
        |> range(start: -7d)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "0_userdata.0.pv.dailyPower")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
        `;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put the import statement directly in the query string:

```
  const weeklyPowerQuery = `
        import "experimental/date/boundaries"
        lastWeek = boundaries.week(week_offset: -1)
        from(bucket: "io")
            |> range(start: -7d)
            |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "0_userdata.0.pv.dayPower")
            |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
          `;
```